# Confusion Matrix in libSvm?

Tags: matlab, libsvm

I am wondering how I can see confusion matrix after classification in libSvm? Here is the basic result of prediction. But I am not sure how to see confusion matrix.Thanks.

```
 optimization finished, #iter = 134
 nu = 0.433785
 obj = -101.855060, rho = 0.426412
 nSV = 130, nBSV = 107
 Total nSV = 130
```

Comment: You can use [confusionmat](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/confusionmat.html) matlab function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't built in function for confusion matrix at libsvm, but you can use matlab confusion matrix function like that

```
[cMatrix,cOrder] = confusionmat(label,predictedLabel);
```